# Retrieving IP address in SlimFramework 3 with rka-ip-address-middleware

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

**Background**

I am creating a `REST API` to work with my mobile app. It is important that I keep a record of any request made to the server by IP address for legality purposes.

I understand people can spoof the IP if they want, but that is not a concern. There is an API key for security, this is simply a CYA precaution.

Using the middleware [Slim 3 suggest here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/ip-address.html) the value is always `NULL` I am testing this from my localhost (If that makes a difference, but I do not know why it would).

**Problem**

When I hit the get request endpoint and I try to capture the IP it is always `NULL`.

**Example**

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    $app->get('/api/v1/customer', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $requestIP = $request->getAttribute('ip_address');
         var_dump($requestIP);
         echo $requestIP;
         echo 'CUSOTMERS!';

        return $response;
    });

$app->run();
```

**Output**

```
NULL CUSOTMERS!
```

**Question**

What is the proper way to capture the `IP address` from the request using this  `rka-ip-address-middleware middleware` in `SlimFrameWork 3`

Comment: Are you actually adding the middleware somewhere? It is not shown in the example code above.

Comment: @MikaTuupola yes thanks mike. I was under the impression that line was for if you needs to pass parameters of accepted IP. I did not realize you can call it with no params. It's all working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
$requestIP = $request->getServerParam('REMOTE_ADDR');
```